# Select multiple options in JS

Tags: jquery, multi-select, selectable

I have following view:

```
<ul id="entries_list">
 <li>a</li>
 <li>b</li>
 <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to have multiselect with shift. When user hold shift and click first and third li then all li's will be selected. I tried Jquery selectable:

```
prev = -1;
$("#entries_list").selectable({
  filter:'li',
  selecting: (e, ui) ->
    curr = $(ui.selecting.tagName, e.target).index(ui.selecting);
    if(e.shiftKey && prev > -1)
      $(ui.selecting.tagName, e.target).slice(Math.min(prev, curr), 1 + Math.max(prev, curr)).addClass('custom_selected');
      prev = -1;
    else
      prev = curr;
```

But the problem is that I have to use custom class 'custom_selected'. In above case It select correctly with shift but is not deselecting. Jquery add own class. Is It possible to overwrite default class? It would be easier if I could use custom class.

Edit:

I have this but It work incorrect:

http://jsfiddle.net/DJFaL/25/

Edit2:

I really sorry but I pasted wrong jsfiddle liks. Now It is correct.

Comment: why aren't you using `<select multiple>` ?

Comment: add a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for better help and add your complete jquery not just a snippit were no one can help with...

Comment: i dont know whats not working... everything works fine... what browser do you have

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use the [select with multiple attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp)? Or simple jQuery for your code?
Anyway, for jQuery I created a demo for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/DJFaL/26/

JS:

```
$('#entries_list li').on('click', function (e) {
    var li = $(this);
    var shift = e.shiftKey;
    if (shift) {
        if (li.hasClass('selected')) {
            li.removeClass('selected');
        } else {
            li.addClass('selected');
        }

    } else {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        li.addClass('selected');
    }
    var array = jQuery('#entries_list li.selected').map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    $('p').text(array.join(','));
});
```

CSS:

```
.selected {
    background-color:#eee;
}
ul {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: moz-none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="entries_list">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>dc</li>
    <li>ddvc</li>
    <li>cvb</li>
    <li>gc</li>
    <li>cdf</li>
    <li>cd5</li>
</ul>Selected li:
<p></p>
```

By default, I used text inside li, you can `$(this).text()` in array map function to any other attribute.